# How do I make my raster layer transparent where there is no data?

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql

I have just managed to load some TIF data into PostgreSQL 11 using raster2pgsql. This test contained just a few files.

When I load the resulting layer into QGIS, the data displays perfectly, expect all blank "no data" areas which are just black.

How can I stop this happening and make these areas transparent? Can I set this transparency back at database level, or can it only be manipulated within the end client (i.e.QGIS)? The ideal solution would be to sort this at database level, saving the hassle of changing it every time it's loaded into a new GIS session.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make specific colors transparent.

You can set colors to be made (fully or partially) transparent here:

`Layer Properties` -> `Transparency` -> `Custom Transparency Options`

[image: Custom Transparency Options]

You can add pixel values:

- either manually ("+" icon)
- or interactively ("arrow and globe" icon) picking the color from the canvas.

I would however investigate in first place if it is possible **not** to have no-data (black) areas imported into PostgreSQL.

Comment: First, you need to solve the black data. It is similar to a numpy array but masked. When you are saving from PostgreSQL to TIF something is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @RafDouglas, that helps in the short term for amending each time someone loads into QGIS, but as you say, I want to sort this back in PostgreSQL so that it either never imports the no data areas, or understands to make them transparent.